# iOS Swift: How to create a multi column hierarchy with UITableView/UICollectionView in landscape mode on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad, uicollectionview

I would like to create an app for iPad (and later adopt it for iPhone) that lets you manage data in four hierarchical levels. Each level depends on the selection you make in the previous level. E.g. first you select a country from a list of countries, then a city from a list of cities in the country and so on.

The Layout is inspired by the Spotify app for the iPad in landscape mode. You can select an artist and then an album by this artist and finally a song. (I didn't attach a screenshot from Spotify, you might know what it looks like.)

The problem is, I can't really find the right approach to create this UI whithin XCode.

I'd start with using four UITableViewControllers or UICollectionViewControllers. But how would I display them on the view at the same time?

I know it's possible to combine multiple view controllers in one parent view controller, e.g. when using a UIPageViewController. But in this case I don't really know what kind of controller to start with.

Right now I show the four UITableViewControllers fullscreen and stacked. But how can I combine them to be shown at the same time and make it possible for the user to navigate through them like in the Spotify App?

[image: Multi column iPad Layout]

Comment: Short update: After a lot of research I found that implementing a Container View Controller might be a good idea :-) I was able to place two UITableViewControllers next to each other. I haven't found out yet how to “scroll“ through the table views, but if I do, I'll make sure to answer my own question – for the container implementation see:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html